# iFolder on ubuntu 10.04 32bits

Tags: 10.04, compiling, ifolder

I'm trying to install iFolder on Ubuntu 10.04 32bits by following the steps presented at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/iFolderInstall.

When issuing the command

```
bzr-buildpackage
```

it seems to download simias.tar.gz and after that, i get the following errors

```
tar -xzvf "simias.tar.gz"
tar: simias.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

The simias.tar.gz file is downloaded as "download".
All you have to do is to add a line in the file "rules" just before the tar command.

```
mv download simias.tar.gz
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the iFolder client on Ubuntu successfully. There are .debs available here:
http://sanjayayogi.com/debs

I found the link in a Google Group about this:
http://groups.google.com/group/ifolder-ubuntu-debian-dev

Here is a useful guide to install iFolder Server on Ubuntu, plus a ton of useful comments:
http://www.x2b4.com/howto/how-to-install-ifolder-on-ubuntu-server
(but I am running an OpenSuse 11.2 virtual machine for it, it's easier.)

Watch out if you run fully encrypted home folders, because you will either have to place your iFolders and the .local/share/simias folder in an unencrypted part of your disk, or recompile Simias.

Comment: Whoa, good to see that the page in the Ubuntu wiki has been very much improved!
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/iFolderInstall
It was very out of date when I tackled my iFolder installation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately iFolder on Ubuntu has never really worked right, despite efforts from multiple people to get it to work, so it's likely the instructions you are following are out of date and unmaintained.

If you need a file syncing service there is [Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com), [Dropbox](http://getdropbox.com), and you can also try [Sparkleshare](http://www.sparkleshare.org/).

Comment: I'm already using ubuntu one and dropbox, but I want to host my files and not store it in the clouds...

Comment: Then you may wish to try Sparkleshare as you can run your own instance.